# Python error: unorderable types: list()<int()

Tags: python

I keep getting the error unorderable types: list()< int(). What am i doing wrong and how should i fix it??

My code:

```
import sys
from List import *


def main():

    strings=ArrayToList(sys.argv[1:])
    numbers=ListMap(int,strings)

    smallest=numbers[0]
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i]<smallest:
            smallest=numbers[i]
    return smallest

    print("The smallest is", smallest(numbers))

main()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "command.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "command.py", line 12, in main
    if numbers[i]<smallest:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()
```

Comment: The error tells you `numbers[0]` is a list too; what is the definition of `ListMap()`?

Comment: What is the module you are importing with `from List import *`?

Comment: And in Python `sys.argv[1:]` is a list of strings *already*. Why the `ArrayToList()` call there?

Comment: Also, just a tip for the future, there is really never a good reason to do `from module import *`.  Doing so dumps a whole bunch of names in the global namespace, most of which you will never use in the code.  Furthermore, these names can easily be overwritten, cause name conflicts, overwrite existing names that you need, etc.

Comment: Looks like `numbers[0]` is a `list` and an `int`. Not Possible. OP, share us the module `List` so that we can also reproduce the same error. Otherwise, any help is futile.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to compare a list with an integer, this is not possible in Python3. Make sure that all items of `numbers` are integers or not.

```
>>> [] < 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-de4ae201066c>", line 1, in <module>
    [] < 1
TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()
```

Comment: I think the problem is more *why is `numbers[0]` a list at all?*