# Vasya - Clerk ----- codewars kata

Tags: python-3.x

The new "Avengers" movie has just been released! There are a lot of people at the cinema box office standing in a huge line. Each of them has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollars bill. An "Avengers" ticket costs 25 dollars.

Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to sell a ticket to every single person in this line.

Can Vasya sell a ticket to each person and give the change if he initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the order people follow in the line?

Return YES, if Vasya can sell a ticket to each person and give the change with the bills he has at hand at that moment. Otherwise return NO.

Examples:
tickets([25, 25, 50]) # => YES 
tickets([25, 100]) # => NO. Vasya will not have enough money to give change to 100 dollars
tickets([25, 25, 50, 50, 100]) # => NO.

can anyone tell whats the issue i get TypeError: unorderable types: list() >= int() error when i click submit

```
def tickets(people):
a=[]

if people[0] ==25:
    a.append(people[0])
    for x in people[1:]:
        if x == 25:
            a.append(people[0])
        else:
            a = sum(a) - x 

    if a >= 0:
        return 'YES'
    else:
        return "NO"


else:
    return 'NO'
```

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python error: unorderable types: list()<int()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150500/python-error-unorderable-types-listint)

Comment: sorry but i  didnot get the solution there!!! can you tell what i am supposed to do in the above code to make that right

Comment: `a` is a list. You cannot compare a list to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely have problems with your variable `a`, which starts out as a list, but in this part of your code, if anyone tries to pay with 50 or 100, you're assigning an integer value to `a` instead

```
if x == 25:
    a.append(people[0])
else:
    a = sum(a) - x
```

And in this line

```
if a >= 0:
```

you're comparing it to an int value 0 -- the way your code is set up, for a test case where each person in line has 25, when your code gets to the above line, `a` will still be a list, and you'll get the error you describe because you're trying to compare a list to an integer.